# How to call Bootstrap Popover from another button or click event?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Based on what I have seen here on the [Bootstrap Component page](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-examples), the popover is attached to the same button performing the call.

Is it possible to show the popover when another button is clicked?

I have a very simple `JQuery` function performing a check.

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){ 

           var status = $('#someTextArea').val();

            if(status === undefined){

                // Show this popover
             }
          }
```

*Popover code:*

```
<a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" role="button"
data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Dismissible popover"
data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging.
Right?">Dismissible popover</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {

    var status = $('#someTextArea').val();

    if(status === undefined) {

        $('a[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('show');

    }
});
```